# Error creating a new user on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a new user on Firebase. But I am getting this error despite activating e-mail auth.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We will need more specifics like the code or something but i think you need to create a notification channel with an specific channel id.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String id = "my_channel_01";
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name,importance);
mChannel.enableLights(true);
mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

First way is to set channel for notification in constructor:

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this , id).setContentTitle("Title");
mNotificationManager.notify("your_notification_id", notification);
```

Second way is to set the channel by Notificiation.Builder.setChannelId()

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this).setContentTitle("Title").
setChannelId(id);
mNotificationManager.notify("your_notification_id", notification);
```

Hope this helps